# What format is this object's key stored in? %00*%00_data

Tags: javascript, text, unicode, utf-8

I have an object with the following key:

```
*_data
```

However, the characters are encoded in a non-standard format that is causing my code some problems.

I saved the value of the key to a cookie, and found the following:

```
%00*%00_data
```

However, when comparing this string (using `==` not `===`) with the value of the key, they are not equal.

Currently I am storing the key's value into a variable and using that variable as the key.  However, I'm extremely curious as to what string I could compare the actual key with that would result in true.

Any help with this mystery would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the key is being stored using *encodeURIComponent*, so use `decodeURIComponent` to decode it, e.g. `console.log(decodeURIComponent('%00*%00_data'))` shows "*_data".

Comment: Amazing.  I used `if (key == decodeURIComponent('%00*%00_data'))` and it returned true!  Thank you!  Please mark as an answer for credit.

Comment: Also, the `===` returned true as well.

Comment: Both values are strings, so whether you use `===` or `==` makes no difference.

Comment: Yes, that is clear now, but you must understand my joy when seeing the `true` result.

Comment: Nah, never had that feeling… eureka? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%00` is the URI-encoded UTF-8 representation of the character *NUL*, representing the null character. I imagine this is used here to differentiate between the actual * character and a * character which may be replaced by some library you're using.

We can get from `%00*%00_data` to `*_data` by using [JavaScript's `decideURIComponent()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), which, as the name suggests, decodes the URI-encoded character:

```
decodeURIComponent("%00*%00_data");
```

Based on your comments, it seems that the `key` variable you're comparing against is actually this string of `length` 8. I mention this, because the string `*_data` you've included in your question is of `length` 6, as it doesn't include the two null characters.